# Add a certain number of bytes to a void pointer in C

Tags: c

I have been banging my ahead on this problem for many hours now. Suppose you have a function that takes an int value as parameter. What I need to do is take this int value and interpret whatever the value is as # of bytes to be added to an address:

```
void* foo(int size){
  node->pointer += size; //assume node->pointer is of type void*
}
```

What the above does is actually add size*4 bytes to pointer because int is 4 bytes. casting this as (char*) i.e.

```
node->pointer += (char*)size;
```

this does't work.
How do I do this in the most simple way?

Comment: Try `node->pointer = (void*)((char*)(node->pointer) + size);`

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I overlooked casting it back to void!

Comment: @squeamishossifrage you don't need to explicitly cast to `void*` because `char*` is automatically converted to `void*`. Right?

Comment: Your title asks how to add a number of bytes to a “void pointer,” but your question implies you are adding to a pointer to `int`, where it says “What the above does is actually add size*4 bytes to pointer because int is 4 bytes.” What is the actual type of `node->pointer`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's void* type

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using GCC extensions ([Pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers and function pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith)) and you're actually using GCC (or Clang), then you can write (more or less) what you wrote using `+=`:

```
void foo(int size)
{
    node->pointer += size; // Not standard — using GCC extension
}
```

It is not standard C, though, and therefore not portable.  From C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011):

> - [§6.2.5 Types ¶19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19): *The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed.*
> - [§6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4): *The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or …*
> - [§6.5.6 Additive operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p2): *For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type.*
> - [§6.5.6 Additive operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p3): *For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:*
>
>   - *both operands have arithmetic type;*
>   - *both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible complete object types; or*
>   - *the left operand is a pointer to a complete object type and the right operand has integer type.*
> - [§6.5.16.2 Compound assignment ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2p1): *For the operators `+=` and `-=` only, either the left operand shall be an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer to a complete object type, and the right shall have integer type; or the left operand shall have atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right shall have arithmetic type.*

Since the `void` type is incomplete and cannot be completed, and therefore a `void *` is a pointer to an incomplete type, you can't use `void` with `sizeof`, nor can you use `void *` with `+` or `-` to do pointer arithmetic, and consequently you can't use `void *` with the compound assignments `+=` and `-=` either.

The standard C equivalent would be:

```
void foo(int size)
{
    node->pointer = (char *)node->pointer + size;
}
```

This code doesn't return a value, any more than yours did (though you said it would because the return type was `void *`).  Since `node->pointer` is a `void *`, you don't need a cast back to `void *`; this is C and the conversion is automatic.

Comment: This is fine in Visual Studio as well. Do you mean it's incompatible in some odd platforms?

Comment: I mean that the C standard says it is not allowed.  I've not yet got my quotes lined up.  One is C11 [§6.2.5 Types ¶19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19); there will need to be others.  But you can't determine the size of an incomplete type, and `void` can't be completed, and to increment a pointer, you need to know the size in bytes, so…but as I said, I've not got all the relevant quotes in place just yet, and I need to take an hour or two out before I can expand my answer — there's some "life" that needs to be lived.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer about what's standard and what's not standard, even though it's written clearly. `node->pointer = (char *)node->pointer + size;` works in Visual Studio, not the other.

Comment: I've added the most relevant sections of the C standard.

Comment: Since there is a C standard way to do this, would’t it be better for an answer to lead with that? The GCC extension seems to add little or no value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — I lead with an explanation of what is wrong with the code in the question. I then show how it can be fixed. And for a depressingly large number of people, “it works in GCC” is sufficient; they don’t care about portability.

Answer (score 0):

writing a sample code for your reference. I used similar concept as answered above.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
 int payload;
 void *ptr;
}*n;

void foo(int x){
 n->ptr = (char *)n->ptr +x;
}

int main(){
  n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  n->payload = 10; //random payload
  n->ptr = n;

  printf("%p\n", n->ptr);
  foo(2); //increment by 2
  printf("%p\n", n->ptr);
}
```